# create a full animation in jquery for a menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new with Jquery and I try to do something too difficult for me.
I try to create a menu with animated links : when you hover a link, a other one'll appear and hide the first link. 
I try with a simple menu and 2 links : one with an `id="link"` and the other with `id="hover"`.

When a mouse is on `#link` (the first link), the `#hover` (the second one) will appear, grow up and hide `#link`.
But, when I put the mouse on `#link` : nothing !!! I test to change CSS and I use Chrome for searching the matter without success.

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
    $("#link").hover(function () {
        $(this).next("#hover").stop().animate({
            display : block, 
            margin-top : -31px, 
            height : 30px
        }, 500);
    },function () {
        $(this).next("#hover").stop().animate({
            display : block, 
            margin-top : -31px, 
            height : 30px
        }, 300);
    });
});
```

```css
#link {
    display : block;
    position : absolute;
    border : 1px solid black;
    height : 30px;
    width : 100px;
}
#hover{
    display : none;
    position : absolute ;
    background-color : orange;
    color : blue;
    height : 0px;
    width : 100px;
}  
nav{
    position : relative;
 height : 100px;
 width :100px;
 border : 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<nav>
    <div id="link">A</div>
    <div id="hover">A</div>
</nav>
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: your snippet is not working... `margin-top` should be wrapped into single quotes `'margin-top'`

Comment: you don't need jquery to create a simple dropdown menu, just google 'css dropdown menu' for tutorials and examples such as this https://codepen.io/philhoyt/pen/ujHzd

Comment: what will be output when mouse is on `#hover` ?